# How can i use SED/AWK to move content of one file to a certain position in another

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file containing just a certificate and I would like to move this over to a second file and overwrite a line in the file.

certificate format will be:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
abc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xyz
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The second file is a yaml file and i want to overwrite Value4 with the certificate

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
```

Output would be

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
abc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xyz
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?. Ideally I dont want to use line numbers because the second file may have new fields added below the certificate in the future.

Comment: Hi @Sundeep this does answer my question. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '
  print /value4/ ? <STDIN> : $_;
' yaml < cert
```

value4 line print the entire stdin else use
regular input.